# Compilation Error When Building OpenSSL for iOS on macOS: 'inttypes.h' File Not Found

Tags: macos, openssl, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am currently in the process of compiling OpenSSL for iOS on my macOS system and have encountered a roadblock that I am hoping to get some assistance with. Here’s a step-by-step breakdown of what I’ve done so far and the issue that I am facing.
1:   Cloning the OpenSSL Repository:
I started by cloning the OpenSSL repository from GitHub using the following command in the terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
```

2:  Setting Environment Variables:
Next, I set up the necessary environment variables for the cross-compilation process. Here are the commands I used:

```
export CROSS_TOP=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/
export CROSS_SDK=iPhoneOS11.3.sdk
export CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64"
```

3:  Configuring OpenSSL:
After setting the environment variables, I ran the configure script for OpenSSL:

```
./Configure iphoneos-cross
```

4:  Running Make:
Finally, I attempted to build the project using the make command. Unfortunately, this is where I encountered the following error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/inttypes.h:21:15: fatal error: 'inttypes.h' file not found
#include_next <inttypes.h>
```

What baffles me is that when I navigate to the include directory and list the contents using ls, I can clearly see that the inttypes.h file is present:

```
@Davids-MacBook-Pro include % ls
... (other files) ...
inttypes.h
... (other files) ...
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or does anyone have insights on what might be going wrong here? I am using Xcode version 15.0 and my macOS version is 12.3. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated as I am currently at a standstill with this issue.

I have double-checked the paths and ensured that the environment variables are set correctly. Yet, the error persists.
also i tried to run

```
xcode-select --install
```

my chip is Apple M1 Pro, macOS 14.0 (23A344), Xcode 15.0.1

i followed https://docs.pjsip.org/en/latest/get-started/ios/build_instructions.html#tls-openssl-support

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why `iPhoneOS11.3.sdk`? Did you manually extract that from an old Xcode version and put that in that location for some reason? With Xcode 15.0.1 you should have `iPhoneOS17.0.sdk`, but that's just a symlink to `iPhoneOS.sdk` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue as you. I solved it by following the instructions on [openssl official guide](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#64-bit).
Here is the full link:
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#64-bit

I hope this will help you.

Regards,
Xiaoyun